# Excel Dynamic Data Validation Based on Adjacent Column

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to piece together some VBA code that would apply data validation (creating a list to use) to a cell based on the value of the cell next to it. I have this functionality working in a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EgnW17LjTrecqWQv6bFWgFdoHKbTJJd-vM5uxFfGMSY/edit#gid=664998834) which I just linked but I don't know anything about VB so I'm struggling with this.

The layout is a little odd with the spreadsheet since the sheet(s) that need this validation have the headers of the rows starting at row 2.

The basics of what's going on is:

- The header of the column that is determining the validation is called "Attribute Group". I want to avoid needing a fixed position so I went with the header name instead of a column index
- When a value changes in "Attribute Group" the cell adjacent to it to the right will have a dropdown created with values corresponding to the value in "Attribute Group"

Please check out the [linked spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EgnW17LjTrecqWQv6bFWgFdoHKbTJJd-vM5uxFfGMSY/edit#gid=664998834) to see this functionality in action. I'm trying to get as close to this as possible in Excel.

Edit: The main question is: how do you create dynamic data validation in Microsoft Excel?

Comment: This has nothing to do with google-apps-script so I removed the tag.

Comment: Use a named range (Eg "MyDataRng") for the range of cells in the Attribute Group then in a list type data validation enter =MyDataRng

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for the edit. I wasn't sure if the tag should be used or not but thought it safer to add.

Comment: @user1302114 I'm not quite sure what you mean with the "... in a list type data validation...".

Comment: In excel you can add data validation to any cell and you can tell it to use a range of cells as the list of valid entries ... it's on the Data tab/menu ,,, You name the range cos I find that easier to enter in the validation form/window/box/field ... Google Excel Data Validation List

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have time to get this working exactly as I would like.

The solution I have now was to create tables for each column that had data that would correspond with the appropriate "Attribute Group".

> Insert > Table
>
> Rename table to match corresponding "Attribute Group" value, removing spaces and special characters
>
> Remove duplicates to get rid of most blank cells then Resize Table if needed to get rid of any others

Then I added data validation in cell E3 using =indirect() as well as substitute() since my "Attribute Group" values had spaces and special characters.

> Data > Data Validation
>
> Under "Settings" I used "List" in the Allow section
>
> The source was =INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D3," ",""),"&","And"))

Then I copied cell E3 and pasted all the way down.
This method solves my current issue but doesn't allow for the level of flexibility that I was hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

Use a named range (Eg "MyDataRng") for the range of cells in the Attribute Group then in a list type data validation enter =MyDataRng

Comment: So you submit an answer not to answer the question but to prevent it from actually being answered?

Comment: No, I answered the question via comments initially then added an answer

Comment: You answered "a" question, but it wasn't mine.

Comment: The question I answered was the very first line of your posting .. "

I am trying to piece together some VBA code that would apply data validation (creating a list to use) to a cell based on the value of the cell next to it"  That is exactly what I described